# In Docker, why is it recommended to run `apt-get` update in the Dockerfile?

Tags: security, docker

Sorry, very new to server stuff, but very curious. Why run apt-get update when building a container?

My guess would be that it's for security purposes, if that the case than that'll answer the question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`apt-get update` ensures all package sources and dependencies are at their latest version, it does not update existing packages that have been installed. It's recommended that you always run `apt-get update` prior to running an `apt-get install` this is so when the `apt-get install` is run, the latest version of the package should be used.

`RUN apt-get update -q -y && apt-get install -q -y <your-program>`

(the -q -y flags just mean that the apt process will run quietly without asking you for confirmations as this would cause the Docker process to fail)

Comment: Adding to the answer, it's not only to get the latest version, but also because the package might be outright missing if the sources are outdated enough, which means `apt-get install` would fail completely.

Answer (score 2):

First, lets make a distinction between `apt-get update` and `apt-get upgrade`. The `update` is to get the latest package index. This is so that you don't run into errors for outdated or redacted packages when doing a `apt-get install`.

The `upgrade` is actually going through an upgrading packages. It usually also requires a preceding `update` to have the updated package index. This might be done if there are package or security concerns of already installed packages.

You usually see an `update` a lot in builds because the base image may have a fairly out of date package index and just doing an `apt-get install` can fail.

The `upgrade` would be less common. But could still be done if you want to ensure the latest packages are installed.